# Limit involving a recursively-defined sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$A_{n+1}=A_n+\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n A_i}$$ with $$A_1=1$$

Find out the value of $$\lim_{n→∞}A_n/\sqrt{\log(n)}$$

I used Stolz Theorem, but it seems to be useless.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could try to look at the sequence $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n A_n$, which has $a_1=1$ and satisfies $$a_{n+1} = 2a_n-a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_n}.$$

Comment: @ClementC. I have tried it, but I didn't find out what to do next.

Comment: The series is increasing. @Clement C.'s method thus suggests the series is divergent.

Comment: But it's the rate of divergence that seems to be the question.

Comment: Using heuristic arguments, the limit should (may) be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ -- not sure it helps. (I can detail below if needed, but if one assumes $A_n \sim_{n\to\infty} B_n = a\sqrt{\ln n}$ and plugs $B_n$ in the recurrence relation, one only has $B_{n+1}-B_n \sim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n B_k}$ for $a = \sqrt{2}$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have that $A_n \ge 1 $ for all $n \ge 1$.

Now let $B_n = {A_n}^2$ and $ C_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n A_k $ so you have  $ C_n \ge n$ , $\frac{1}{C_n} \le \frac{1}{n}$, $A_n  =A_1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{C_k} \le 1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = 1+H_n = O( \log(n))$ and $C_n = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k =  \sum_{k=1}^n O( \log(k)) = O(n\log(n))$.

Moreover $B_{n+1}={A_{n+1}}^2 = {A_n}^2 + \frac{1}{ {(\sum_1^n A_i)}^2} + 2 \frac{A_n}{(\sum_1^n A_i)} = B_n + \frac{1}{{C_n}^2} + 2\frac{A_n}{C_n}$.

Since $    \frac{1}{{C_n}^2}  =  o\left(\frac{A_n}{C_n}\right)$, $B_{n+1}-B_n \sim 2 \frac{A_n}{C_n}$, therefore $B_n \sim 2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{A_k}{C_k}$.

Now you have for all $k\ge2$ ,$  \frac{A_k}{C_k}  \le \int\limits_{C_{k-1}}^{C_k} \frac{dt}{t}$ so $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{A_k}{C_k}  \le \int\limits_{C_{0}}^{C_n} \frac{dt}{t}= \log({C_n})$.

I let you do the other inequality to show that $ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{A_k}{C_k}  \sim \log({C_n}) \sim \log(n)$.

So finally  $A_n \sim  \sqrt{ 2\log(n)}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, it was a typo.

Comment: Nice solution! ${}$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. To this end, we write $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_k$. Then we prove the claim using a series of observations, extensively relying on [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

---

> **Claim 1.** $A_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

*Proof.* Assume otherwise. Since $(A_n)$ is increasing, this implies that $(A_n)$ is bounded. Let $C = \sup_{n\geq 1} A_n$. Then $S_n \leq Cn$, and so,

$$ C \geq A_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{S_k} \geq 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{Ck}. $$

Since the right-hand side diverges as $n\to\infty$, this is a desired contradiction. $\square$

---

> **Claim 2.** $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n A_n}{S_n} = 1$.

*Proof.* Note that $S_n \geq n A_1 = n$. Then the desired conclusion follows from Stolz–Cesàro theorem together with the estimate

$$ \frac{ n A_n - (n-1)A_{n-1}}{S_n - S_{n-1}} = 1 + \underbrace{ \frac{(n-1)}{A_n S_n} }_{\leq \frac{1}{A_n} \to 0} \to 1. $$

---

> **Claim 3.** $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A_n}{\sqrt{\log n}} = \sqrt{2}$.

*Proof.* It suffices to prove that $A_n^2/\log n \to 2$. Then the claim follows by Stolz–Cesàro theorem applied to the estimate

\begin{align*}
\frac{A_{n+1}^2 - A_n^2}{\log(n+1) - \log n}
&= \underbrace{ \frac{1}{n \log(1 + 1/n)} }_{\sim 1} \biggl[ \underbrace{ \frac{2nA_n}{S_n} }_{\sim 2} + \underbrace{ \frac{n}{S_n^2} }_{\leq \frac{1}{S_n} \to 0} \biggr] \to 2.
\end{align*}